# Calling two functions in Windows batch file one after the other

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have two scripts which are to be executed and i am using Windows batch script for automating of running the scripts.

I have to read 10 user input values and then run the two scripts using those parameters.

I am successful in executing the first script and failing with the second script.

Issue is that the cmd prompt exits after completing the first script.

How to make cmd prompt run the second script as well using the input parameters.

Any Help on this??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show us the code you already have. Do you use the `call` command for both scripts ? If not is it clear why your calling batch gets interrupted after calling the first script.

Comment: Please post your code. No code --> no help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to execute a batch script from you code. It's either `START` or `CALL`:

- `START` will execute your code in it's own variable **scope**, means the variables you've set in the first script won't be available. Further both scripts will be executed in parallel and not one after another (unless you use `START /WAIT`).
- `CALL` on the other hand will do exactly what you need. It will start the first script in the **same scope** (previously set variables are variable), execute it and afterwards it will run the second sript (also in the same scope).

TL;DR this will work:

```
...
CALL BatchScript1.bat
CALL BatchScript2.bat
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you call scripts from another script you have to use the `call` command:

```
@echo off
call first.cmd
call second.bat
echo Here I'm back again !
```